# This riddle could be extremely useful

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I was created long ago, more than fifty years in fact.
Back then there were just six in me, held together by a pact.

Next I did increase by three, but one of them will leave.
Then one more came in alone, and I did almost grieve.

My next addition was a pair, but they were both close by.
Then did come another three, and I extended high.

One summer warm some years ago, I grew and grew in size.
The largest change I'd ever seen - so many new allies.

Two more and then a final one, my history is complete.
Identify me and you'll get - a checkmark for a treat.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you

> The European Union?

```
I was created long ago, more than fifty years in fact.
Back then there were just six in me, held together by a pact.
```

> Created in 1957 between Belgium, France, Italy, Luxembourg, the Netherlands and West Germany, via the Treaty of Rome

```
Next I did increase by three, but one of them will leave.
Then one more came in alone, and I did almost grieve.
```

> Denmark, Ireland, and the U.K joined, the U.K will leave. (Brexit) Greece then joined, and is the EU economy currently struggling most. (grieving?)

```
My next addition was a pair, but they were both close by.
Then did come another three, and I extended high.
```

> Portugal and Spain joined next, Germany was reunified(not mentioned) and then Austria, Sweden, and Finland joined. This extended the EU to the north (high)

```
One summer warm some years ago, I grew and grew in size.
The largest change I'd ever seen - so many new allies.
```

> To quote Wikipedia "In 2004, the EU saw its biggest enlargement to date when Cyprus, the Czech Republic, Estonia, Hungary, Latvia, Lithuania, Malta, Poland, Slovakia and Slovenia joined the Union."

```
Two more and then a final one, my history is complete.
Identify me and you'll get - a checkmark for a treat.
```

> Romania and Bulgaria, followed by Croatia

Comment: Identify me and you'll get - a checkmark for a treat. --> 'czech mark'???

Comment: @AvikMohan Unintentional, but clever!

Comment: "Almost grieve" is meant to be a "change one letter" clue: Greece -> Greeve -> Grieve.

Comment: Also, did you spot the clue in the title?